# how to include all values of an attribute

Tags: c#, xml

Working with an XML currently

```
<Company>
  <Employee>
    <FirstName Initial="A" Totaldigits="six" Lastletter="T"/>
    <FirstName Initial="A" Totaldigits="six" Lastletter="Y"/>
    <FirstName Initial="A" Totaldigits="six" Lastletter="A"/>
 </Employee>
</Company>
```

Since values of `Initial` and `Totaldigits` don't change, I get their values.

I am looking to get the values of all `Lastletter` attributes (so 'T','Y', 'A')

Using this in C#, in `FirstName`, I am only getting the first value in `Lastletter` which is "T",

```
string digit = root.Attribute("Lastletter").Value;
```

What should I change/add to this line to get all of `Lastletter` values?

Comment: `What should I change/add to this line` - a `foreach` loop over the respective `root`s?

Comment: @GSerg can you elaborate, looping individually?

Comment: You're at the wrong node then -- from the `Employee` node you can do `employee.Elements("FirstName").Select(e => (string) e.Attribute("Lastletter"))`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert this gives cs0029 error that  

`cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumrable<System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute>' to 'string'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression loops on all the elements named **Employee** then iterates *its* child elements named **FirstName** and applies an expression that:

1. Ensures element *has* an `Attribute` named **Lastletter**
2. If so, dereferences its `Value` property

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var root = XElement.Parse(source);
    foreach (var employee in root.Elements("Employee"))
    {
        var lastLetters = 
            employee.Elements("FirstName")
            .Where(match => match.Attribute("Lastletter") != null)
            .Select(match=>match.Attribute("Lastletter").Value);

        Console.WriteLine($"Last Letters: {string.Join(",", lastLetters)}");
    }
}
const string source =
    @"<Company>
        <Employee>
            <FirstName Initial=""A"" Totaldigits=""six"" Lastletter=""T""/>
            <FirstName Initial=""A"" Totaldigits=""six"" Lastletter=""Y""/>
            <FirstName Initial=""A"" Totaldigits=""six"" Lastletter=""A""/>
        </Employee>
    </Company>";
```

[image: console output]

---

If the goal is to have a one-liner, you could try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var root = XElement.Parse(source);
    String[] results =
        root
        .Elements("Employee")
        .Select(employee => 
            string.Join(
                ",",
                employee.Elements("FirstName")
                .Where(match => match.Attribute("Lastletter") != null)
                .Select(match => match.Attribute("Lastletter").Value)
            )
        )
        .ToArray();

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Last Letters: {result}");
    }
}
const string source =
    @"<Company>
        <Employee>
            <FirstName Initial=""A"" Totaldigits=""six"" Lastletter=""T""/>
            <FirstName Initial=""A"" Totaldigits=""six"" Lastletter=""Y""/>
            <FirstName Initial=""A"" Totaldigits=""six"" Lastletter=""A""/>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <FirstName Initial=""B"" Totaldigits=""six"" Lastletter=""I""/>
            <FirstName Initial=""B"" Totaldigits=""six"" Lastletter=""D""/>
            <FirstName Initial=""B"" Totaldigits=""six"" Lastletter=""K""/>
        </Employee>
    </Company>";
```

[image]